# Evolution mail and calendar icon not going away

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, icons, uninstall, evolution

I installed Evolution mail and calendar from the software center. I didn't like it and so I   uninstalled. But the icon is not going from the dash menu.

Software center: http://flic.kr/p/dAuiM6
Dash: http://flic.kr/p/dAzLS1

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you removed Evolution, it didn't clean up a .desktop file.

.desktop files are what Unity uses to list launchers in the Dash. There are a few places it looks for these:

- ~/.local/share/applications
- /usr/share/applications
- ~/Desktop

The top two are the most likely. Just find the one for Evolution (probably Evolution.desktop) and delete it. You may have to reload Unity (`alt`+`f2` then type in "unity" and click the icon that appears) for it to take effect.

Comment: I found that in the first location. I deleted and the icon is gone.Thanks